# WSO2 API Store - How do I allow a user to update their profile details (claims)

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, claims, wso2-identity-server

Regarding the WSO2 Store app is it possible to allow a user to update their own account details? By default the menu only has the Privacy option - which only allows the password to be updated.

[image]

I'm confused as how to configure the store to allow the user to update additional details, e.g. their email address.

There's a great article [here](http://blog.lakmali.com/2013/12/wso2-api-manager-customizing-store-user.html) detailing how to customize the required claims when signing up, however I'd like to allow the user to edit their claims after having signed up, and possibly also customize that update page.

Perhaps this is possible by editing the Jaggery app itself? I notice that the `user-info.jag` file (used to update the password) calls `mod.changePassword(username, currentPassword, newPassword);` `mod` being an instance of `jagg.module("user");` is it possible to update other claims in the same way?

Or is there an easier way to allow a Store user to update their claims?

The updated claims must also be persisted through IS.

Answer (score 0):

After you create the a new user you have to assigned the necessary permission for that particular user by using the carbon console in API Manager.

- So first logging as a admin to the carbon console and create a new role and assign the required permissions to that role.
- Then assign that role to the user that you have created.
- logout form the carbon console.
- Then login using the new user that you have created.
- Then you can edit the profile details in the particular user that you have logged in depending on the permission that you have assigned to the user role(Carbon Console).

Thanks,
ojith

Answer (score 0):

Hope this link would be helpful for your confusion -  https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM131/Adding+Users+and+Assigning+Roles

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge you can't register as a user in api manager store without submitting following details.

1. username
2. Password/Re-type Password
3. Last Name
4. First Name
5. Email

These are mandatory details to register as a user, additionally you can add following details Organization,Address,Country,Land Phone,Mobile Phone, IM, URL also.After you register as a user it will only allow to change your password.

else if you have permission to log in to carbon/Management console in WSO2 api manager select " Users and Roles" under the "Configure" menu you can see the users who added already.By editing "User Profile" you can update account details.